# Iterating through elements in an array by memory address. (C)

Tags: c, pointers

Im new to C. I have a const unsigned short array of 1024 hex numbers. each hex number represents is 8 bits and represents bits to be turned on and off when displaying an image to a GBA screen. But nevermind all that and the DMA syntax I have below just for reference!!

My main question is...how can I iterate through elements in an array BY ADDRESS, grab those contents, then continue incrementing through addresses? Also, if you could give a stare to the below code and maybe see why Im getting:

```
"Program.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `myimg'"
```

on the line that calls "drawImage3" and that would be rad.

(in the main of program.C):

```
const unsigned short *pt;  
pt = &myimg[0]; 
int size = 5;
drawImage3(15,15,img_WIDTH,img_HEIGHT, pt);
```

(defined elsewhere):

```
void drawImage3(int x, int y, int width, int height, const u16* image)
{
    int r;
    for (r=0; r<height; r++)
    {   
        DMA[3].src = &image;
        DMA[3].dst = &videoBuffer[OFFSET(x+width, y, 240)];
        DMA[3].cnt = width | DMA_SOURCE_FIXED | DMA_ON |   DMA_DESTINATION_INCREMENT;  
        image++;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `DMA[3].src` to the address of a pointer, which is probably not what you want to do.  For clarity's sake, here's what these references mean:

```
*image    -- the value of the thing which image points to
 image[0] -- same as *image
 image    -- the location in memory of your thing
&image    -- the location in memory that is storing your pointer
&image[0] -- same as image
&image[n] -- the location of the nth element in your thing
```

So instead of `DMA[3].src = &image;`, you probably want one of these two:

```
DMA[3].src = &image[r];    # If you do this do NOT increment image
```

or

```
DMA[3].src = image;        # And continue to increment image
```

If you choose the latter, then

```
DMA[3].src = image;
image++;
```

Can be better written as:

```
DMA[3].src = image++;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided, `myimg` is never defined (line two in the second code block).

As for looping by address, arrays are already pointers, so doing a simple for loop is the same as looping over addresses. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the 'looping by address' business though, because that's what C is already doing.

EDIT:

AFAIK, arrays don't really exist in C, but they do in C++, so indexing into an 'array' is just saying, 'give me a chunk of memory starting at this address and this many bytes * size into it'.

For example, an int array (4 bytes per index) is just a chunk of memory that is `4 bytes * number of indexes`.  Getting an index into this 'array' is just getting a memory offset x bytes * 4 (sizeof int) into the memory chunk.

Simply put, you shouldn't have to worry about it much.

Comment: I added a little info about what I understand arrays to be.

Comment: Not sure what all this new-fangled terminology is, but arrays in c are pretty much pointers.

Comment: @Perception that is a very misleading and inaccurate thing to say. @tjameson arrays are basically the same in C and in C++; the only meaningful difference is that in C++ you can create a reference to an array. Everyone should read http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html thoroughly.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado - I beg to disagree. Arrays (const pointers) and pointers are much more similar in C/C++ then arrays in other languages that support ***real*** properties like for example, the *length* attribute.

Comment: I think arrays are a little more array-like in c++ because you can use the new operator to declare a 'new' array. Since new doesn't exist in c, and since 'new' is just malloc or something similar under the hood, there really isn't a big difference. I just think C++ makes a clearer distinction between a memory block and an 'array'. Sure, arrays in C++ aren't an object, just a memory chunk, but it's a little clearer distinction in my mind.

Comment: @Perception: Arrays are NOT pointers!  There are properties of arrays that are unique to them that pointers just don't have.  Sure we can use arrays _almost_ exactly the same as pointers but it is entirely wrong to say that they are equivalent.  Consider the size of an array versus a pointer.  e.g., `int arr[20]` versus `int *ptr` (assuming a 32-bit architecture).  What would be the value of `sizeof arr`?  Of `sizeof ptr`?  Don't confuse C or C++ arrays with array objects found in OO languages, these are completely different concepts.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado - read my first comment carefully - I said in C, not in C++ ;)

Comment: @Jeff Mercado- I can assign an array to a pointer `void* ptr = myarray` directly without any addressing concerns. To the compiler, it's basically the same thing, except in the case where I use array syntax. With a regular pointer, it will work by bytes (if I'm not mistaken), whereas with an array it will work by whatever the size of the element is. This is a compile time thing. To the runtime, pointers and arrays are exactly the same and will treat them the same always. In OOP languages, arrays are a class/object, not just a chunk of memory with intelligent addressing.

Comment: @Perception, tjameson: Well I won't be able to convince you guys otherwise so I'm not going to drag this any longer.  So I'll just leave a few links I've been able to scrounge up that explains this and hopefully you'll find out the truth for yourselves.  (http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=arrays+are+not+pointers) (http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) (http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/687fcae0d3ecb089?hl=en)